# Get value from lua_State in C++ fail

Tags: c++, lua

I want to get the value in struct lua_State, but I find the value goes wrong.

```
void func(lua_State* L)
{
        lu_mem nBytes     = 0;
        int    stacksize  = 0;
        int    sweepstrgc = 0;
        lu_mem estimate   = 0;

        nBytes     = L->l_G->totalbytes;
        stacksize  = L->stacksize;
        sweepstrgc = L->l_G->sweepstrgc;
        estimate   = L->l_G->estimate;
}
```

Like the example above, for example, the totalbyes is 1270000, but the nBytes get 6 all the time. What's the problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems strange. But for sure you are accessing private members of Lua implementation, not supported by the API. For debug, those values could make sense to display, but otherwise I don't think custom code should read internal Lua structures.

Answer (score 0):

/* actual number of total bytes allocated */
gettotalbytes(g) =  (g)->totalbytes + (g)->GCdebt